# firewall-cmd (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six')

Tags: centos, python, firewall, pip

I'm try to open port using `firewall-cmd` but I get error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'`.

I'm try to reinstall `six` using `easy_install`, `pip`, `pip3` and `pip3.6` but it not work.

```
os: centos 8
python: 3.6.8
pip 20.1.1
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all this issue happen due to python setuptools issue , by mistake or intentionally you upgrade it , and then after upgrade i think you reinstall six module by you or one of the libraries , what happen it will not install it correctly after upgrade in the correct path all you need is to run this command , it will move the six lib file to it's correct path so other modules can find it

```
cp /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
```

Comment: thanks obeid. you saved my time.

Comment: Honestly, this answer just pushes off the problem to the next time the user uses pip to install something.  They should be reinstalling the RPM(s) and not installing random stuff as root with pip.

Comment: @jsbillings Thanks for reply dear. I prefer using containers to avoid this type of errors. but in my case some one installed many packages as root then I get this error and didn't know how to solve it. after hours of search I cant find solution so this answer fine for me (just for now). can you help me to solve this problem with professional way.

Answer (score 1):

From https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1663220 :

> Force reinstalling the python3-six command did the trick;
>
> ```
> $ sudo dnf reinstall python3-six
> ```

Worked for me too (AlmaLinux 8 ~= CentOS 8).